# using tone.js within angular6

Tags: angular, tone.js

I'm trying to import tone.js in angular 6. As mention in tone.js installation [doc](https://github.com/Tonejs/Tone.js/wiki/Installation), I installed tone.js.

```
npm - npm install tone
```

I tried to import Tone in app.module.ts

```
import { ToneJs } from 'tone';
imports: [
   ToneJs,
   ...
]
```

I got this exception:

```
Error: Unexpected value 'undefined' imported by the module 'AppModule'
```

How I can import and use tone.js with angular?

Here my angular version

```
ng -v
Angular CLI: 6.0.1
Node: 8.11.1
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 6.0.1
```

Edit:

When I try to load it in a component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ToneJs } from 'tone';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-player',
  templateUrl: './player.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./player.component.css']
})
export class PlayerComponent {  
    constructor(private toneJs: toneJs) { }
}
```

I get:

```
Error: Can't resolve all parameters for PlayerComponent: (?).
```

Comment: Looks like you're trying to add `ToneJS` to the `imports` declarations of an `NgModule`, but ToneJS is not an Angular module.

Comment: I don't think your import is correct, the docs require/import `Tone` whereas you're importing `ToneJs`.

Comment: Try importing tonejs as `import * as Tone from 'tone';`
and add this line `declare var Tone: any; // i am assuming you dont have typings for ToneJS`
and in your constructor check if Tone is defined. (typeof Tone !== 'undefined'). If its defined you can start using it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using angular-cli, you could try adding the ToneJS library to your angular.json as an external script

```
projects
- architect
  - build
    - scripts
      - [ ..., "node_modules/path/to/Tone.js"]
```

if you dont have a typings.d.ts file at src/typings.d.ts, create this file and add this line
`declare var Tone: any;`

Now, ToneJs should be available for you to use throughout the app as a Global variable. So you can use it like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-player',
  templateUrl: './player.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./player.component.css']
})
export class PlayerComponent {  
    constructor() { 
        // const loop = new Tone.Loop((time) => { 
            // do something 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that works... But I already use an class Tone in my app. How can I change Tone to ToneJs for example?

Comment: You could maybe do it the other way around. When you import your Tone class, import it as ToneClass instead - `import { Tone as ToneClass } from 'path/to/Tone.ts';` or just update the class definition so its clear across the application.
Since ToneJS is a thirdparty library, you cant rename the global variable directly to ToneJS.

Comment: You can do import ToneJs from 'tone', it works as default import. You can also do deep imports if you only want to include what you use in your js bundle. For example, import Transport from 'tone/Tone/core/Transport'

Answer (score 2):

Someone named [Dylan Lawrence](https://stackblitz.com/@dylanlawrence) created [a nice starter](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tone) I found while googling on this topic this morning. Super helpful!