# How to display a keyboard using Tone.js UI in Angular?

Tags: angular, tone.js

In an `Angular 7` application I installed the `Tone.js` dependency:

```
npm install tone
npm install @tonejs/ui
```

I can play notes and I would like to display a keyboard using the `tone-keyboard` element I saw at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yotammann/spzgucvw)

My `synth.component.html` file contains:

```
<tone-demo autoplay>
  <tone-keyboard octaves="3"></tone-keyboard>
</tone-demo>
```

My `synth.component.ts` file contains:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import Tone from 'tone';
```

But I get the following error:

```
Error: : 'tone-keyboard' is not a known element:
```

Should I have some additional `import` statement in the `synth.component.ts` file ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50710954/using-tone-js-within-angular6

Comment: Did you read my question ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var synth = new Tone.Synth().toMaster()

//play a 'C' for one 8th note
synth.triggerAttackRelease('C4', '8n')


var synth = new Tone.AMSynth().toMaster()

startNote = (event) => {
   synth.triggerAttack(event.target)
}

endNote = (event) => {
   synth.triggerRelease()
}

//Mouse click starts the note 
<Button onMouseDown={this.startNote}/>

//Mouse click ends the note 
<Button onMouseUp={this.endNote}/>





var jakeSynth = new Tone.Synth({
  oscillator : {
    type : 'fmsquare',
        modulationType : 'sawtooth',
        modulationIndex : 3,
        harmonicity: 3.4
  },
  envelope : {
    attack : 0.001,
        decay : 0.1,
        sustain: 0.1,
        release: 0.1
  }
}).toMaster() 

jakeSynth.triggerAttackRelease('B2', '8n')


For more detail visit link:-
https://tonejs.github.io/
```

Comment: You seem to showcase how to play a note. That I can already do. I would like to display a keyboard. Did you see the keyboard displayed in the fiddle ?